# Activating jupyter_contrib_nbextensions in JupyterLab

Tags: jupyter-lab, jupyter-contrib-nbextensions

I have installed jupyter_contrib_nbextensions using conda, i.e.: `conda install -c conda-forge jupyter_nbextensions_configurator`

This is what I see:

[image]

I don't see extensions I expected to see like `toc2` extension.

In fact, I am trying to configure my JupyterLab Notebook to provide the following functionalities:

[image]

When I select the functionalities of interest the button "enable" is dimmed.

[image]

This is how my JupterLab appears:

[image]

What I am missing?

Answer (score 7):

Just in case someone else is looking for this, the nbextensions won't work in **JupyterLab**. From [jupyter-contrib-nbextensions documentation](https://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html) as of 8/31/2021:

> Most nbextensions here should work fine with jupyterhub (because jupyterhub spawns regular notebook servers for each individual user), but won’t work with jupyterlab (because the jupyterlab javascript framework is different to notebook’s, and still rapidly changing under active development).

There are [extensions](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extension/extension_tutorial.html) available within JupyterLab, and of course, a [framework](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extension/extension_dev.html) for creating your own extensions.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using nbextensions you can use 2 @jupterlab extensions that will have the result that you want. To install the jupyterlab extensions first you will need to Enable Extensions Manager by checking this option on the settings menu.

Then, you need to click on the Extension Manager icon in the left side (as indicated on the figure bellow), agree with the disclaimer and then clikck in the install link after the extension name.

[image: The arrows indicate the steps]

The extensions that make what you need are:

- @jupyterlab/toc-extension
- @aquirdturtle/collapsible_headings

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the boxes, (or select them and click `Enable`).

[image: updated_image]

Comment: Please see my edited question.  The button 'enable' appears dimmed and still I don't see these functionalities activated in my JupyterLab notebook.

Comment: `Enable` is dimmed because when you check the box it automatically becomes enabled. You may have to restart your jupyter server for the changes to take effect.

Comment: Thank you, I did restart it though.